# Waiting for API response in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

(background)
I have an ERP application which is managed from a Weblogic Console. Recently we noticed that the same activities that we perform from the console can be performed using the vendor provided REST API calls. So we wanted to utilize this approach programatically and try to build some automations.

This is the page from where we can control one of the instance [ConsoleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uiAV.png)
The same button acts as Stop and Start to manage the start and stop instance.

Both the start and stop have different API calls which makes sense.
The complete API doc is at : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E61420_01/doc.92/e80710/smcrestapis.htm#BABFHBJI

(Now)
I wrote a program in python using the request method to call these APIs and it works fine.
The API response can take anywhere between 20 to 30 seconds when I use the stopInstance API
And normally takes 60 to 90 seconds when I use the startInstance API, but if there is an issue when starting the instance it takes more than 300 seconds and goes into indefinate wait.

My problem is, while starting an instance I want to wait maximum only for 100 seconds for the response. If it takes more than 100 seconds the program should display a message like "Instance was not able to start in 100 seconds"

This is my program. I am taking input from a text file and all the values present there have been verified.

```
import requests
import json
import importlib.machinery
import importlib.util
import numpy
import time
import sys

loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('SM','sm_details.txt')
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(loader.name, loader)
mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
loader.exec_module(mod)
username = str(mod.username)
password = str(mod.password)
hostname = str(mod.servermanagerHostname)
portnum = str(mod.servermanagerPort)
instanceDetails = numpy.array(mod.instanceName)

authenticationAPI = "http://"+hostname+":"+portnum+"/manage/mgmtrestservice/authenticate"
startInstanceAPI = "http://"+hostname+":"+portnum+"/manage/mgmtrestservice/startinstance"

headers = {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
}

data = {}
data['username']= username
data['password']= password
instanceNameDict = {'instanceName':''}

#Authentication request and storing token
response = requests.post(authenticationAPI, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
token = response.headers['TOKEN']
head2 = {}
head2['TOKEN']=token

def start(instance):
    print(f'\nTrying to start instance : '+instance['instanceName'])
    startInstanceResponse = requests.post(startInstanceAPI,data=json.dumps(instance), headers=head2) #this is where the program is stuck and it does not move to the time.sleep step 
    time.sleep(100)
    if startInstanceResponse.status_code == 200:
        print('Instance '+instance['instanceName']+' started.')
    else:
        print('Could not start instance in 100 seconds')
        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the timeout parameter in requests:

```
requests.post(startInstanceAPI,data=json.dumps(instance), headers=head2, timeout=100.0)
```

> You can tell Requests to stop waiting for a response after a given
> number of seconds with the timeout parameter. Nearly all production
> code should use this parameter in nearly all requests. Failure to do
> so can cause your program to hang indefinitely.

**Source**
[Here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts)'s the requests timeout documentation, you will also find more details in there and Exception handling.

Comment: hi Pitto,Thank you for reading through this huge post and taking out time to reply. I will try this option and do some more testing.